# Is it possible to install an RPM in a RPM?

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild

Can I create an RPM which contains and puts an RPM in a directory, and install that RPM?
How?

Comment: This sounds like a really, really, really bad idea, not only because RPM db locking won't allow you, but also because it sounds like you're trying to "invert" how packaging works. What's the motivation here? I'm almost certain there's better ways to implement what you're trying to achieve, but I don't know exactly what that is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no. The problem (at it's most basic) is that the RPM database is open during all phases of installation, so when you try to install the second package, it tries to open (for exclusive access) a database which is already open (for exclusive access), and you end up with (hopefully) a failure to open and a nasty error message or (worst case) a corrupt RPM database.

To solve the problem I think you're trying to solve, you want to specify the second package as a dependency inside the SPEC file of the first package.